# DHE key exchange with p value 257 bytes but a pubkey of 256 bytes

Tags: cryptography, wireshark, key-exchange, diffie-hellman

I came across a packet capture in Wireshark where p length = 257 bytes and pubkey length = 256 bytes. See the ServerKeyExchange snip below:

```
Diffie-Hellman Server Params
    p Length: 257
    p: 00a81c7b6633732007ba19bf733fc5f6cf5d0c9f8e03ec4c3caebbe392bb8830b5cb1144…
    g Length: 1
    g: 05
    Pubkey Length: 256
    Pubkey: 8b55fc1f255a06c2619bc44a398df6feeefdc236ab376fbcfe3908b30c41b5d5aac4847a…
    Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha256 (0x0401)
    Signature Length: 256
    Signature: 66b99953613dc8650a465e9b9cf8187e29df14fe5e758086772393fec9c41a4956703b4e…
```

In the ClientKeyExchange length of pubkey = 257 bytes as below:

```
Diffie-Hellman Client Params
    Pubkey Length: 257
    Pubkey: 0095bd9694bbfaf4d30520ce013cb6487a67c7e2d4735ecf58f4dab3b322893c256c539c…
```

The SSL handshake is successful. I'm curious to know how and why?

Aren't the length of pubkey in ServerKeyExchange and ClientKeyExchange supposed to be the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length as such doesn't matter; the *numeric value* does. Both publickey values -- Ys and Yc -- must be numerically less than p (and greater than one), and both your examples are.

The numbers used in 'classic'/modp/Zp DHE, now retronymed finite-field DHE = FFDHE, are always positive, and are encoded in SSL/TLS as unsigned, so leading zero bytes don't affect the value. The minimum size *needed* for either Y value is not greater than that needed for p, and *most of the time* it is equal, but about half a percent of the time (at random) it is actually smaller.

However, the 'bignum' features or libraries used in SSL/TLS implementations often handle signed as well, and may need a leading zero byte on numbers that would otherwise have the high bit set because that is used as the representation for a negative number, which we don't want here. It may not be worth the trouble of removing or avoiding that 'extra' byte.
SSL/TLS does not require minimum-length encoding of numbers so it would be legal, though silly, to add even more (redundant) leading zero bytes up to the encoding size limit  of 65535 bytes. This might be a good place for more 'GREASE' if practically everybody weren't now using elliptic curves (ECDHE/XDHE) instead of FFDHE.

In contrast both ASN.1 DER/BER and SSH use signed (two's complement) minimum-length, so for them the 'extra' zero is sometimes required and sometimes prohibited, but the numeric values still follow the rule above. (PGP doesn't use FFDH, but for similar algos uses unsigned with the length implied from the exact number of significant bits, which is necessarily minimum-length.)

Comment: Neatly explained! Thanks for your answer.